# Reading/Writing files in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, file-io, fopen, fread

I'm trying to make a web app that will read in a server-side CSV file and display it in a neat, browsable format. The catch is that I want to do it in naked JS/CSS3/HTML5. **Is there any way to read and write server-side files with naked JS/CSS3/HTML5?** I obviously want this to be OS/browser  independent.

### What I've tried

---

I *have* tried implementing some code I found online (a few sites reference it). Below is what I tried while testing: (I just want the test to show the contents of the webpage, itself, in the webpage)

[`scriptTest.htm`](http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/JS/scripttest.htm):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="readIt.JS"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="return readIt();">Show the code of the page</button>
<div id="readItOutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[`readIt.JS`](http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/JS/readIt.JS):

```
function readIt()
{
    file = fopen(getScriptPath("scriptTest.htm"), 0);
    file_length = flength(file);
    content = fread(file, file_length);
    document.getElementById("readIt").innerText = content;
}
```

However, whenever I run it, under Opera and Chrome, it throws the following:

**Opera:**

```
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: fopen
Error thrown at line 3, column 1 in readIt() in http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/JS/readIt.JS:
    file = fopen(getScriptPath("scriptTest.htm"), 0);
called from line 1, column 0 in <anonymous function>(event) in http://s.supuhstar.operaunite.com/s/content/JS/scripttest.htm:
    return readIt();
```

**Chrome:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getScriptPath is not defined
readItreadIt.JS:3
(anonymous function)scripttest.htm:6
onclick
```

Comment: Have you considered using XHR ("Ajax") to pull the desired file and then parsing the commas and lines? You can't directly write server files with this method (you'd have to ask a server-side script to do that for you via XHR), but you can "read" a file this way and parse its contents.

Comment: Matt's absolutely right. You can get the file contents with AJAX and then format however you want.

Comment: @Matt what part of XHR is "**naked JS/CSS3/HTML5**"?

Comment: @Supuhstar Pretty much all of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit some files from server you need to use XHR object to download file to client side and again use XHR object to send modifed data back to server, also you need some sort of API on you server to send/recieve data.

Comment: what part of XHR is "**naked JS/CSS3/HTML5**"?

Comment: @Supuhstar See my comment to your OP above. XHR is standard implementation on all popular modern browsers' Javascript engines. Javascript would be highly violatile if it was permitted to read and write the local file system or that of a remote server, even writing to files on the same domain as the origin of the request. This is why those tasks have to be delegated to local scripts which have authorization to run. On a client machine, you basically won't get it. Period. On your server, you can authorize a script or program, invoked by an XHR request, to perform a write operation.

Comment: @Supuhstar whole XHR is "naked JS", beacuse you get it in any browser without any additional libraries

Comment: by the way you can look into Node.js, it slightly blurs the line between client side and server side

Answer (score 1):

File writing cannot be done with JS/CSS3/HTML5 alone for security reasons, otherwise people would be able to modify the js in FireBug and write a file.
You would need to create an API of some sort using either server-side JS or a language such as PHP to handle the permissions, file names, file locations, etc…

As for reading, your file would have to be publicly accessible, otherwise you'll need it served by a server-side language such as PHP.

Comment: Just clarified my answer - reading can only be done with JS if the file is publicly accessible - i.e. can be accessed in your browser without javascript.

Comment: The file certainly is publicly accessible.